# Datewise sum of active users based on status column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a status_log table having the following columns:

```
User_id, isactive, date
1, 1, 1 Jan 2020
2, 1, 1 Jan 2020
3, 1, 2 Jan 2020
2, 0, 5 Jan 2020
4, 1, 10 Jan 2020
4, 0, 10 Jan 2020
3, 0, 12 Jan 2020
```

Isactive signifies whether the user was active on that day onwards, untill the day when isactive is set to false. Subsequently the user can decide to become isactive again. And so on.

I want to return a result with 2 columns. Column 1 should be the date starting from the 1st ever date from the status_log table. It should have a date irrespective of whether the day is in the status_log table. Against each day I want to have the sum of users that were active on that day. The sum should include all users who are active as of that day - so those that has the isactive set to true on or prior to that date and are not having inactive set to false immediately prior.

I am trying to work out the algorithm for this:

1. Create a date table containing all the dates from 1st date of the table till last date.
2. Do a left join from the table from step 1 and the status_log table.
3. I am stuck here - for each row perform a sum based on the partition of all prior dates, order by date and include only those that have isactive set on that day or preceding day. How can I ensure that the logic restricts itself to the active user only.

Expected output:

```
Date, activeusers
1 Jan - 2
2 Jan - 3
3 Jan - 3
4 Jan - 3
5 Jan - 2
6 Jan - 2
7 Jan - 2
8 Jan - 2
9 Jan - 2
10 Jan - 2
11 Jan - 2
12 Jan - 1
```

Comment: please show some sample data and the required output

Comment: for `Create a date table containing all the dates from 1st date of the table till last date`, you can use a permanent calendar table or `recursive cte` to create one on the fly

Comment: I was wondering if there is a SQL way to get it instead of date table.

Comment: Recursive cte as mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive common table expression to generate the dates and count the number of active users as you iterate. An alternative would be to generate all dates at first and perform the count.

1. Find log start and end date (`cte_period`).
2. Generate all dates for the entire period by joining the previous limits with a tally table (`cte_num` & `cte_dates`). This tally table allows for log periods up to 27 years. You can add an extra `cross join` if you would need 273 years.
3. Count the number of active users (`count(distinct sl.user_id) ... sl.isactive = 1`) for each date (`group by cd.date`). These active users have no deactivation record up until the current date (`not exists ... sl2.isactive = 0`).

**Sample data**

```
create table status_log
(
  [user_id] int,
  [isactive] bit,
  [date] date
);

insert into status_log (user_id, isactive, date) values
(1, 1, ' 1 Jan 2020'),
(2, 1, ' 1 Jan 2020'),
(3, 1, ' 2 Jan 2020'),
(2, 0, ' 5 Jan 2020'),
(4, 1, '10 Jan 2020'),
(4, 0, '10 Jan 2020'),
(3, 0, '12 Jan 2020');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte_period as
(
  select min(sl.date) as date_start,
         max(sl.date) as date_end
  from status_log sl
),
cte_num as
(
  select row_number() over(order by (select null))-1 n
  from       (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n) -- 10 days
  cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n) -- 100 days
  cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n) -- 1000 days (2.7 years)
  cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n) -- 10000 days (27.3 years)
),
cte_dates as
(
  select dateadd(day, cn.n, cp.date_start) as [date]
  from cte_period cp
  cross join cte_num cn
  where dateadd(day, cn.n, cp.date_start) <= cp.date_end
)
select cd.date,
       count(distinct sl.user_id) as activeusers
from cte_dates cd
left join status_log sl
  on  sl.date <= cd.date
  and sl.isactive = 1
  and not exists ( select 'x'
                   from status_log sl2
                   where sl2.user_id = sl.user_id
                     and sl2.date <= cd.date
                     and sl2.date >= sl.date
                     and sl2.isactive = 0 )
group by cd.date
order by cd.date;
```

**Result**

```
date        activeusers
----------  -----------
2020-01-01  2
2020-01-02  3
2020-01-03  3
2020-01-04  3
2020-01-05  2
2020-01-06  2
2020-01-07  2
2020-01-08  2
2020-01-09  2
2020-01-10  2
2020-01-11  2
2020-01-12  1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a05d791c85ff19a91c2cc20b89fcd40b) to see things in action with intermediate results.